# Share Kaniko Cache for Multi Stage Docker Builds with CloudBuild

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build, kaniko

I am working on a CloudBuild script that builds a multistage Docker image for integration testing. To optimize the build script I opted to use [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko). The relevant portions of the Dockerfile and cloudbuild.yaml files are available below.

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  # Build BASE image
  - name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.17.1
    id: buildinstaller
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>-installer:$BRANCH_NAME
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>-installer:$SHORT_SHA
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=24h
      - --cache-repo=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>/cache
      - --target=installer
  # Build TEST image
  - name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.17.1
    id: buildtest
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>-test:$BRANCH_NAME
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>-test:$SHORT_SHA
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=24h
      - --cache-repo=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>/cache
      - --target=test-image
    waitFor:
      - buildinstaller
  # --- REMOVED SOME CODE FOR BREVITY ---
  # Build PRODUCTION image
  - name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v0.17.1
    id: build
    args:
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>:$BRANCH_NAME
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>:$SHORT_SHA
      - --destination=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>:latest
      - --cache=true
      - --cache-ttl=24h
      - --cache-dir=/cache
      - --target=production-image
    waitFor:
      - test # TODO: This will run after tests which were not included here for brevity
images:
  - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine AS installer

# Expose port
EXPOSE 3000

# Set desired port
ENV PORT 3000

# set the app directory var
ENV APP_HOME /app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_HOME}
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

# Install necessary packanges
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
  build-base curl less libressl-dev zlib-dev git \
  mariadb-dev tzdata imagemagick libxslt-dev \
  bash nodejs

# Copy gemfiles to be able to bundle install
COPY Gemfile* ./

#############################
# STAGE 1.5: Test build #
#############################
FROM installer AS test-image

# Set environment
ENV RAILS_ENV test

# Install gems to /bundle
RUN bundle install --deployment --jobs $(nproc) --without development local_gems 

# Add app files
ADD . .
RUN bundle install --with local_gems

#############################
# STAGE 2: Production build #
#############################
FROM installer AS production-image

# Set environment
ENV RAILS_ENV production

# Install gems to /bundle
RUN bundle install --deployment --jobs $(nproc) --without development test local_gems 

# Add app files
ADD . .
RUN bundle install --with local_gems

# Precompile assets
RUN DB_ADAPTER=nulldb bundle exec rake assets:precompile assets:clean

# Puma start command
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]
```

Since my Docker image is a multi-stage build with 2 separate end stages that share a common base build, I want to share the cache between the common portion and the other two. To accomplish this, I set all builds to share the same cache repository `- --cache-repo=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/<MY_REPO>/cache`. It has worked in all my tests thus far. However, I have been unable to ascertain if this is best practice or if another manner of caching a base image would be recommended. Is this an acceptable implementation?

I have come across [Kaniko-warmer](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#caching-base-images) but I have been unable to use it for my situation.

Comment: I am struggling with this too. I originally had my destinations set as different images, and without the `--cache-repo` argument there was no re-use of cached layers between images. I changed my steps to build different *tags* of the same image, and no longer needed that argument. Then a `cache` image appeared in my repo, and caching worked between steps. I'm also not sure whether this is the correct way to do it though.

Comment: I am trying to build this in a single shot (I only care about the final image) and I get an error saying : No cached layer found for cmd COPY --from=builder /venv /venv

Comment: Besides caching, [`--skip-unused-stages`](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/README.md#--skip-unused-stages) may also benefit your builds. This flag will for example ensure your production build will not build the test image as well.

Answer (score 7):

Before mentioning any best practices on how to cache your base image, there are some best practices in order to [optimize the performance of your build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds). Since you already use Kaniko and you are caching the image from your repository, I believe your implementation is following the Best Practices above.

The only suggestion I would make, is to use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds#caching_directories_with_google_cloud_storage) to reuse the results from your previous builds. If your build is taking a long time and the files produced are not a lot and it doesn't take a lot of time to copy them *from* and *to* Cloud Storage, this would speed up more your build.

Furthermore there are some best practices that are stated in the following article, regarding the [Optimization of your build cache](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-for-building-containers#optimize-for-the-docker-build-cache). I believe the most important of them is to:

"position the build steps that change often at the bottom of the Dockerfile. If you put them at the top, Docker cannot use its build cache for the other build steps that are changing less often. Because a new Docker image is usually built for each new version of your source code, add the source code to the image as late as possible in the Dockerfile".

Finally another thing I would take into consideration is [the cache expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/kaniko-cache#configuring_the_cache_expiration_time).

Please keep in mind it must be configured appropriately in order not to lose any updates for the dependencies but not running builds without any use.

More links you may consider useful (bare in mind that these are not Google sources):

[Docker documentation about Multi-stage Builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

[Using Multi-Stage Builds to Simplify And Standardize Build Processes](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/multi-stage-builds-and-dockerfile-b5866d9e2f84)